# Nesting types in interfaces

Tags: typescript

So, I'm just trying to break down all the various types and interfaces for my project.

Most of my data structures use an `external_id`

I created a `base.interface.ts` file:

```
export type ExternalId = string;
```

Now, in my audit interface `audit.interface.ts`, I want to use that ExternalId

```
import { ExternalId } from "Interfaces/base.interface";

export interface IAudit {
  [ExternalId]: number; <---- this doesn't work, how to fix?
}
```

Finally, in the component that uses Audit interface, there might be multiple:

`component.interface.ts`

```
import { IAudit } from "Interfaces/audit.interface";

export interface IComponent {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  audits: { <--- this object could be empty or have 10 audits, the data example:
    "external_id_111": 1,
    "external_id_112": 1,
    "external_id_113": 1,

    maybe 
    audits: Partial<IAudit> ?

  }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Cheerio!

Comment: in your last code block `audits` is an object. Every key can only be in an object once. So you can't have `external_id` twice

Comment: Is `audits` supposed to be an array/tuple?

Comment: @catgirlkelly nah, it's an object of ids and numbers `{ "id_123": 1, "id_222": 1, "id_555": 1 }`

Comment: So, could you clarify that in the question?

Comment: I don't think you can limit the number of properties in an object like this.

Comment: @catgirlkelly I don't want to limit anything, I just want to use the correct typescript to say, `audits` will have multiple or none children of `"external_id_111": 1` or `string: number`

Comment: Why not just use `interface IAudit { [key: string]: number; }` then?

Comment: so why does `audits: IAudit` not work for you? Assuming you fixed the type like this `type IAudit = { [K: ExternalId]: number }`

Comment: @HereticMonkey See posted answer. I think that looks correct

Comment: @TobiasS. See posted answer, I think that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, looks like I was trying to over complicate.

This seems to look correct:

`audit.interface.ts`

```
export interface IAudit {
  [key: string]: number;
}
```

`component.interface.ts`

```
import { IAudit } from 'Interfaces/audit.interface';

export interface IComponent {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  audit: IAudit;
}
```